# What number follows up next?

Tags: number-sequence, number-theory

I'm currently working on a (difficult) number progression and need your help. How would you continue?

2, 5, 12, 25, 54, 113, 240, 481  ?

Thanks in forward!

Comment: sorry had to edit it! After 54 it goes 113, 240, 481

Comment: [OEIS A063807](https://oeis.org/A063807)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@OP: When posting number sequence puzzles, or when looking for the next number in a sequence, do check the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS)](https://oeis.org/) for the sequence. Many sequences are listed there, so the chances are you will often find what you're looking for there.

Posting this answer as a community wiki as it is unfair to gain reps off an OEIS sequence.

---

[OEIS A063807](https://oeis.org/A063807) defines this as:

> $a(0) = 0, \text{ and } a(n+1) = a(n) + (\text{next prime larger than } a(n))$.
>
>  For instance:
>  $$0+2=2$$
>  $$2+3=5 $$ 
>  $$5+7=12  $$
>  $$12+13=25 $$ 
>  $$25+29=54 $$
>  $$\cdots$$
>
>  Hence the sequence is 
>  $$0, 2, 5, 12, 25, 54, 113, 240, 481, 968, 1939, 3888  $$

Comment: Sorry got a little overexcited with the editing...never did one for a community wiki before :P

Comment: LOL :-) @NL628 and thanks for the formatting cleanup!